# Related product to have quantity added to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, related-products

I need related products to have a quantity input on the view page and for the add to cart button to carry this quantity to the cart with the product.

Can anyone advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

put below code in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml`

```
<?php if(!$_item->canConfigure() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
    <form  method="post"  id="event_form" action="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_item) ?>" >
        <input id="qty" name="qty" type="text" value="1" >
        <button type="submit"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```